# iOS app icon is not visible on the device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have developed an app in iOS but it's app icon is not visible.The app icon is visible in xcode but not in device.I have added the icon images first into my images group & from there i drag & drop the images to the specific device icon set. All files are copied into my COPY BUNDLE RESOURCES but still the icon is not visible any body tell me the reason for that?

Comment: Have you added all icon resolutions icon120-120@2x.png, Icon-120@2x.png, Icon-80@2x.png, Icon-60@2x.png, Icon-Small-40@2x.png like this way.

Comment: have added the all resolution does naming convention matter ?

Comment: How have you added the images? Did you use image assets or you just added icons to the project? How many targets do you use? Make sure that added images are in the target you use to build the application.

Comment: I create new app icon set then i add images into my images folder in project & then i drag n drop the images to icon sets.

Comment: I don't think image name is a matter. Have you specified icons through plist file.

Comment: By icon set you mean AppIcons in Images.xcassets ? Did you choose in target settings to use thеsе icons?

Comment: In your project settings open the settings for your target. In "General" Tab look at "App Icons and Launch Images" section. In "App Icons Source" drop down menu choose the image.xcassets where you put the icons. Or you need to edit your info.plist. In it add "Icon files" key and add the names of your icon files in the array.

Comment: not working.Icon showing is xcode but not in device.